# How can I add a user to a protected branch?

Tags: gitlab-api

I would like to configure my gitlab project so that every maintainer can merge (after review) but nobody can push on `master`; only a bot (for release).

I'm using terraform to configure my gitlab, with something like this:

```
resource "gitlab_branch_protection" "BranchProtect" {
  project            = local.project_id
  branch             = "master"
  push_access_level  = "no one"
  merge_access_level = "maintainer"
}
```

But with have a "premium" version and the terraform provider do not allow to add a user (goto: https://github.com/gitlabhq/terraform-provider-gitlab/issues/165 ).

So, what I like to do is doing some http request on the API to add the specific user.
So I'm doing it like this:

1. get the actual protection
2. delete the actual configuration
3. update the retrieved configuration with what I want
4. push the new configuration

BTW: I've not found how to just update the configuration... https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/protected_branches.html

```
TMP_FILE=$(mktemp)
http GET \
    $GITLAB_URL/api/v4/projects/$pid/protected_branches \
    PRIVATE-TOKEN:$GITLAB_TOKEN \
    name=$BRANCH_NAME \
    | \
    jq \
    --arg uid $USER_ID \
    '.[0] | .push_access_levels |= . + [{user_id: ($uid | tonumber)}]' \
    > $TMP_FILE

http DELETE \
    "$GITLAB_URL/api/v4/projects/$pid/protected_branches/$BRANCH_NAME" \
    PRIVATE-TOKEN:$GITLAB_TOKEN

http --verbose POST \
    "$GITLAB_URL/api/v4/projects/$pid/protected_branches" \
    PRIVATE-TOKEN:$GITLAB_TOKEN \
    < $TMP_FILE
```

But my problem is that the resulting configuration is not what I expect, I've got something like this:

```json
    "push_access_levels": [
            {
                "access_level": 40,
                "access_level_description": "Maintainers",
                "group_id": null,
                "user_id": null
            }
        ],
```

How can I just update the branch protection to add a simple user ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok like they say: RTFM !

But you need to delete the rule before adding the new configuration.

```sh
http \
    DELETE \
    "$GITLAB_URL/api/v4/projects/$pid/protected_branches/$BRANCH_NAME" \
    PRIVATE-TOKEN:$GITLAB_TOKEN \

http \
    POST \
    $GITLAB_URL/api/v4/projects/$pid/protected_branches \
    PRIVATE-TOKEN:$GITLAB_TOKEN \
    name==${BRANCH_NAME} \
    push_access_level==0 \
    merge_access_level==40 \
    unprotect_access_level==40 \
    allowed_to_push[][user_id]==$USER_ID \
```